# issue in keras model combination

Tags: python, lambda, keras, deep-learning

I have a model1 input:(?,?,?,3) and have 4 output, but I am gonna use only the second one with an outputshape:(?,1) and last one with an outputshape:(?,1,21)
I want to construct a new model based on model1 as follow:

```
def helper(x):
    x1 = x[0]
    x2 = x[1]
    indices = tf.where(tf.greater(x1, 0.2))
    res = tf.gather_nd(x2, indices)
    res = tf.reduce_sum(res, 0)
    res = tf.expand_dims(res,0)
    return res

x1 = model1.outputs[1]
x2 = model1.outputs[3]
output1 = keras.layers.Lambda(helper)([x1,x2])
output = keras.layers.Dense(100)(output1)
newmodel = keras.models.Model(model1.input, output)
```

but there is one error in `output = keras.layers.Dense(100)(output1)`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-5a7a962556f8> in <module>()
      2 x2 = model1.outputs[3]
      3 output1 = keras.layers.Lambda(helper)([x1,x2])
----> 4 output = keras.layers.Dense(100)(output1)
      5 newmodel = keras.models.Model(model1.input, output)

~/.conda/envs/21/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
    430                                          '`layer.build(batch_input_shape)`')
    431                 if len(input_shapes) == 1:
--> 432                     self.build(input_shapes[0])
    433                 else:
    434                     self.build(input_shapes)

~/.conda/envs/21/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py in build(self, input_shape)
    870                                       name='kernel',
    871                                       regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
--> 872                                       constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
    873         if self.use_bias:
    874             self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(self.units,),

~/.conda/envs/21/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~/.conda/envs/21/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in add_weight(self, name, shape, dtype, initializer, regularizer, trainable, constraint)
    247         if dtype is None:
    248             dtype = K.floatx()
--> 249         weight = K.variable(initializer(shape),
    250                             dtype=dtype,
    251                             name=name,

~/.conda/envs/21/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/initializers.py in __call__(self, shape, dtype)
    207             scale /= max(1., fan_out)
    208         else:
--> 209             scale /= max(1., float(fan_in + fan_out) / 2)
    210         if self.distribution == 'normal':
    211             # 0.879... = scipy.stats.truncnorm.std(a=-2, b=2, loc=0., scale=1.)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Please help me figure it out!
thanks in advance!

Comment: could you show what is that `helper`?

Comment: helper() is in the codes, I typed the wrong name, sorry about that. Now I correct the codes in the question.

Comment: would you mind showing `print(output1)`, something like `<tf.Tensor 'lambda_1/ExpandDims:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32>`. Also, try define a `output_shape` to the Lambda layer. I guess there are shape error in this line: `K.variable(initializer(shape),`

Comment: @NathanExplosion You are right! It turns out to be the problem of ``output_shape`` of the Lambda layer. Why didn't I find the issue of ``output_shape``, this problem has bothered me for almost two days! Is it because of my poor knowledge of keras or tensorflow? Can you offer me some advice on how to learn the keras and tensorflow? Thanks a lot!

Comment: just carefully read the Trackback error information and track the error. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that error is that you need to define the `output_shape` for `Lambda` layer. Because the error from `K.variable(initializer(shape)` indicates that something wrong with the shape.

For Tensorflow backend, the `output_shape` can be automatically calculated. Take a look at the source code: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/core.py#L561 . For your situation I may need mode details of your `[x1,x2]` to track why that error happened.

But anyway, it is always good to define the `output_shape` of Lambda layer manually.